# XGBoost with transformed data

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I came across with a data analysis that created an XGboost model for binary classification problem. In the dataset there are some numeric columns (payment, salary etc.) These columns were transformed into the log of them, so their logarithms were taken into new columns and were used in the analysis. Could there be any reason to it? XGBoost is not sensitive to monoton transformations as I understand. The objective is logistic:binary, does it have to do anything with logistic regression? If this is the objective, then the algorithm doesn't work with trees, but runs logistic regressions and it boosts the weights of the wrongly classified samples in that process?

Thank you!

Comment: You are quite correct with your first belief; XGBoost is not at all sensitive to monotone transformations.  It may be that the columns were transformed to help with the scale of various plots, or that the data analyst didn't realize that taking the log wouldn't change the result.